# Can't restore my progress on Tiny Tower

Tags: technical-issues, tiny-tower

I started playing Tiny Tower on my phone almost a year ago. I played on my phone and had gotten 19 golden tickets. I then backed up my progress and started playing on my tablet using my email address. I am now sitting at 29 golden tickets and can't figure out how to transfer my progress from my old tablet to the new one. It keeps restoring the game to the point where I backed it up on my phone. I can view my progress under past towers but I can't play from there. Someone please help I don't want to lose the 10 golden tickets. I still have access to the game on my old tablet which has the 29 golden tickets.